# :hover + :not - как оптимально реализовать?

Tags: css, hover

Столкнулась со следующей проблемой, которую хотелось бы решить лаконичнее в одну строку.
Необходимо чтобы при наведении  на пункты меню появлялось подчеркивании, но его не было на логотипе: 
[image: Скриншот]
Сам код менюхи выглядит так:

Пробовала так (не работает):

```css
.menu > ul> li>  a:hover:not(.logo){
    border-bottom: solid 2px #1a1a1a;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
       <li class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="INK TATTOO"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Find us</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
  </nav>
```

Может косякнула в псевдоклассах? И можно ли такое реализовать в одну строку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

именно, косяк. Если следовать вашему css, класс `.logo` должен быть не у `li`, а у ссылки `a`

```css
.menu > ul> li>  a:hover:not(.logo){
    border-bottom: solid 2px #1a1a1a;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="INK TATTOO"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Find us</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Блин, косяк( Спасибо